# How to poll for a signed url?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, polling

I need to poll an image using javascript, and perform an action once the image is found.  Here is the code I am using:

```
    pollUpload(file) {
        const stopTime = Number(new Date()) + (1000 * 60)
        const check = (resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const img = new Image()
                img.onload = resolve
                img.onerror = () => {
                    if (Number(new Date()) < stopTime) check(resolve, reject)
                    else reject(new Error('Timed out'))
                }
                img.src = file
            }, 1000)
        }
        return new Promise(check)           
    },
```

This works, but I am running into the problem where after the first GET, which is a 404, the response gets cached, and subsequent requests don't get sent everytime.  So it can take awhile before it works.

The standard solution to this is just to append a timestamp to the querystring.  However, here is my trouble:  These images are secured using aws signed urls.  So the url needs to exactly match the form generated by aws, and cannot have any random info appended to it.

Are there any other recommended ways to prevent a broken url from being cached, in this situation?

Comment: Can I politely ask _why_ you are polling a Signed URL? If you can explain your scenario, we might be able to offer an alternative approach that does not require such polling (eg using a queue).

Comment: @John - Certainly.  This is part of an image upload script.  An upload request gets sent to the server, which responds with a generated s3 upload url, and the url of the (to-be uploaded) image.  Once the image is then uploaded to s3 from the browser, a lambda is triggered that takes care of the image processing and the moving of the image file to its final destination.  I suppose it would be possible to setup long polling of SQS, to know when the job completes.  However I was hoping it would be possible to just poll the image url directly, as that seems simpler.  (If it can be made to work)

Comment: So, is the above code waiting for the upload to complete, so that it can trigger a Lambda function to do the image processing? Or is it polling the final destination to get the post-processed picture?

Comment: The second case -- polling of the final destination begins immediately after the image has been uploaded to s3, to get the processed image once the lambda completes.  The lambda is automatically triggered by the upload to s3.